# A local software to create invoices and receipts

Tags: online-payment

I desire a local software (a software that runs directly on an operating system without requiring a web browser and/or a web server) to create invoices and receipts which is:

1. FOSS
2. Windows and Linux oriented
3. Can be easily synced with data synchronization software such as:

   - Microsoft OneDrive
   - Amazon Drive
   - Google Drive (via Google Backup and Sync)
   - Apple Drive (iCloud)
   - Others<sup>I should make *USB flash drive* backups as well.</sup>

One more element I also desire is the ability to have invoices and receipts generally identical beside their title (headline); so the headline for an invoice would be "invoice" and the headline for a receipt would be "receipt", and the other is the same, as with:

> **Providing entity's name:** John Smith
> **Providing entity's identity number:** 000-000-000
> **Identity number of state:** Cambodia
> **Providing entity's email:** john@smith.com
> **Providing entity's telephone number:** +855 000-000-000
> **Number of document:** 328
> **Date:** 22/06/2020
> **Sum:** 40 USD
> **Work details:** `X`
> **Sidenote:** `X`
> **To:** CUSTOMER_DETAILS

If I don't have that ability than I should be able to custom the course code of this software to have that feature.

Comment: We're looking for something like this too. Currently we're using just Excel templates